# Usage the "currentDirectory&" variable in a path (.Vbs)

Tags: variables, vbscript

What is wrong with this script

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
currentDirectory = left(WScript.ScriptFullName,(Len(WScript.ScriptFullName))-(len(WScript.ScriptName)))
WshShell.Run "C:\Windows\System32\diskpart.exe /s currentDirectory&"\vhd.txt", 1, True
```

I mean I know the "currentDirectory&" usage is wrong but couldn't correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) To get the **current directory**, use .GetAbsolutePathName on .\ or .CurrentDirectory:

```
>> WScript.Echo goFS.GetAbsolutePathName(".\")
>> WScript.Echo CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory
>>
E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\28892856\vbs
E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\28892856\vbs
```

(2) To get **script's directory**, use .GetParentFolderName on WScript.ScriptFullName:

```
>> WScript.Echo goFS.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
>>
M:\bin
```

(3) To build a file spec from a path and a file name, use .BuildPath:

```
>> WScript.Echo goFS.BuildPath("a\", "\b")
>>
a\b
```

Compare this to

```
>> WScript.Echo left(WScript.ScriptFullName,(Len(WScript.ScriptFullName))-(len(WScript.ScriptName))) & "\vhd.txt"
>>
M:\bin\\vhd.txt
```

Inventing your own hacks puts you at risk (which native or - more evil - user defined functions/subs will (not) tolerate the `\\`?) without any benefits.

(4) Unlike other languages, e.g. Perl, VBScript neither interpolates/substitutes variable content into string literals, nor evaluates functions or operators in them:

> > body = "BODY"
> >     WScript.Echo "head & body & tail"
> >
> > head & body & tail ' <--- string literal unchanged

The concatenation operator & has to be used out of the literals:

```
>> body = "BODY"
>> WScript.Echo "head" & body & "tail"
>>
headBODYtail
```

**Update wrt tarkan's comment** "really funny I'm always getting an error could someone correct the last line of the code please":

To prove that Serenity's code is not funny at all:

```
>> WScript.Echo "Notepad " & Chr(34) & "c:\windows\win.ini" & Chr(34)
>>
Notepad "c:\windows\win.ini"
```

Comment: something is still missing

 Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
 currentDirectory = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory
 WshShell.Run "C:\Windows\System32\diskpart.exe/s" &CurrentDirectory& "\vhd.txt", 1, True

Answer (score 0):

Quotes enclose text you type. & joins strings together. Variables containing strings are not quoted.

To make a full string Current directory must be outside of quotes.

```
x = "I'm a string" & Im_a_variable_containing_a_string & "I'm another string"
```

Often paths need to be quoted. A double set of quotes within quotes or Chr(34) joined.

```
x = """C:\windows\win.ini""" 'or
x = "Notepad ""C:\windows\win.ini""" 'or

x = Chr(34) & "c:\windows\win.ini" & Chr(34)
x = "Notepad " & Chr(34) & "c:\windows\win.ini" & Chr(34)
```

Comment: really funny I'm always getting an error could someone correct the last line of the code please

Answer (score 0):

```
 "C:\Windows\System32\diskpart.exe /s " & CurrentDirectory & "\vhd.txt"
```

if quotes needed

```
"C:\Windows\System32\diskpart.exe /s " & """" & CurrentDirectory & "\vhd.txt"""
```

or

```
"C:\Windows\System32\diskpart.exe /s " & Chr(34) & CurrentDirectory & "\vhd.txt" & Chr(34)
```

If one wants to see a string one is making one msgboxes it.

Comment: Employ someone. You obviously have no idea about programming OR operating windows.

Comment: all the answers helped me  , thanks For a simple script like this I don't need to employ someone  . I can just use the 'exact path' (tested and worked) but  with currentDirectory& variable "It doesn't work"

Answer (score 0):

here is my final script (works) of course without currentDirectory& :) , but I have learned valuable infos about "currentDirectory" Thanks again to everyone

```
 If WScript.Arguments.length =0 Then
  Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")


  objShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", Chr(34) & _
  WScript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34) & " uac", "", "runas", 1
Else
'--------------
Dim objFSO, outFile
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
'Open write stream
Set outFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\vhd.txt", True)

'Write each command line
outFile.WriteLine "select vdisk file=d:\win_10.vhd"
outFile.WriteLine "attach vdisk"
outFile.WriteLine "select vdisk file=d:\win_8.1.vhd"
outFile.WriteLine "attach vdisk"

'Close write stream
outFile.Close

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
WshShell.Run "C:\Windows\System32\diskpart.exe /s C:\vhd.txt", 1, True

Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
obj.DeleteFile("C:\vhd.txt")
'--------------
'End of UAC workaround code
End If
```

And Finally with Currentdirectory :)

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sCurPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".")
WshShell.Run "C:\Windows\System32\diskpart.exe /s " & sCurPath & "\vhd.txt""", 1, True
```