# VB save file in called script location

Tags: vbscript, save, location

I am trying to create a script that will grab the computer system info of a network user that logs in and then put that info into a txt doc that I can use later to put them into a spreadsheet for inventory purposes.

I have gotten the script to work but the issue is that it is saving the file to the folder that has the calling `.bat` file, but I want it to save in the location of the `.vbs` script.

The `.bat` file is a basic login script that points to the `.vbs` script in another folder.

Here is the obj creation for the `.vbs` script

```
' Open File For Writing

Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Dim objFileSystem, objOutputFile
Dim strOutputFile

' generate a filename base on the script name

strOutputFile = "./" & Split(WshNetwork.ComputerName, ".")(0) & ".txt"

Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.fileSystemObject")
Set objOutputFile = objFileSystem.CreateTextFile(strOutputFile, TRUE)
```

the location I want to save it to is a shared folder with path

```
\\\server\\_pcinfo
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28931866/603855

Comment: Thank you, Working properly now.